# Flask can't find templates, gives 500 error

Tags: python, flask

so I've started coding using Flask framework and found it pretty easy. I am following a tutorial on youtube and got an error. I installed python, pip, flask and set environment variables and everything. My structure looks like this:

```
/first_project
   /template
      template.html
      home.html
   routes.py
```

Here is my template html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Flask App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My home html:

```
{% extends "template.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h2>Hello World!</h2>
{% endblock %}
```

And lastly my `routes.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I run it at localhost:5000 and I'm getting a `"GET /HTTP/1.1" 500 -` in my command line. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Which tutorial are you following?

Comment: The console where you're running Flask should show you the trace-back

Comment: @WillCampbell This one sir http://bit.ly/1JBPNRo

Comment: @Cfreak this is only what I see in my console http://i.imgur.com/3fu4oTw.png

Comment: Turn on debugging. Its a keyword arg to `app.run()`.  Change to `app.run(debug=True)`

Comment: Are you sure you installed Flask locally (in your directory, first_project)?

Comment: @Cfreak Tried that and got jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: home.html

Comment: @WillCampbell I just created a directory in one of my drives.. but yes I installed flask

Comment: OH change template to templates (the folder name)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Appears to be you just misnamed your folders. Flask uses the keyword "templates" when looking through directories.

Change template to templates and you should be fine.